# Are Hilbert spaces smooth?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm new in functional analysis. I have a question about smooth normed spaces.

A normed space $X$ is called smooth if for every $0\neq x\in X$, there exists a unique functional $\varphi \in X^*$ such that $\| \varphi \|=1$ and $\varphi (x)=\| x\|$.

Is a Hilbert space smooth?

Comment: I think yes; $\varphi(x)=\left\langle {x\over \|x\|} , \cdot\right\rangle$

Comment: @lisarus: Your map is not linear

Comment: OP's statement should follow from Hahn Banach in a straighforward manner though.

Comment: @Leonid The existence of at least one $\varphi$ is implied by Hahn-Banach. The uniqueness is what makes the space smooth, and it doesn't hold in general.

Comment: lisyarus's answer should clearly be $\varphi(\cdot)=\left\langle {x\over \|x\|} , \cdot\right\rangle$ instead; the $x$ is fixed. This does make the map linear.

Comment: @Theo Bendit: You're right. I didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4398764/442  Since the dual of Hilbert space is Hilbert space, it suffices to show Hilbert space is strictly convex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the other guys said in the comments, the existence of a functional $\phi$ such that $\phi(x)=||x||$ and $||\phi||=1$ is due by a direct consequence of Hahn-Banach theorem of normed spaces.

If you want to add the uniqueness condition, then you have to add the fact that your space is Hilbert, in particular that it holds Riesz Representation Theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#Riesz_representation_theorem

A clear functional for Hilbert spaces that satisfies your condition is the following:

$$ \phi_x(y):=\langle y, \frac{x}{||x||}\rangle $$

Now let us suppose to have another functional $\phi$ that satisfies your condition, so $||\phi||=1$ and $\phi(x)=||x||$. By Riesz representation theorem there exists $x’$ such that

$$\phi (y)=\langle y, x’\rangle$$

and $||x’||=||\phi||=1$.

But then

$$||x’-\frac{x}{||x||}||^2=\phi(x’)+ \phi_x(\frac{x}{||x||})-2\phi(\frac{x}{||x||})\leq 1^2+1-2=0$$

Thus $x’=\frac{x}{||x||}$ and so $\phi=\phi_x$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @M.Ramana You’re welcome 